# Fetch data from network when network connection is available in a scheduled service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentservice, android-networking

I have an app that effectively kicks off an intent service every 5 hours (from boot) to fetch data from the network.

What I want to achieve is if there is no network connection (at the time of fetching), subscribe to some broadcast to listen to when a network becomes available and fetch data again.

What is the best approach/technique to achieve this?

Also, I would probably want to cancel the subscription (for network connection broadcast), after I have successfully fetched the data this way, and reset the original service schedule so it checks again in 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I did was allowed my Broadcast receiver via the manifest (which kicks of my intent service) to listen for **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE**. i.e. this enabled me to listen for changes in the network.

Now in my intent service, if data failed to fetch due to network connection, then I would set a flag in shared pref called "waiting_for_connection";

If on network changed I would check the "waiting_for_connection" flag and if set. If false, then I would just return; otherwise I would proceed to fetch data only if there is a network. And if successful, I would reset the flag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (SharedPreferences)http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
for store string 5 hours and string validate with true  false (0/1) and than check string validate in every 5 hours it is true or false, and change validate in every 4.59 hour  finished

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean? I already have a service being kicked off via an alarm service to run every 5 hours.